# Ruby symbols to#proc with puts

Tags: ruby, function

I'm learning ruby for 2 weeks but i have a problem you probably now that

```
words = ["hello", "world", "test"] 
words.map do |word|
     word.upcase
end
```

is equal to

```
words = ["hello", "world", "test"] 
words.map(&:upcase)
```

but why that

```
m = method(:puts)
words.map(&m)
```

work ??

Answer (score 2):

[`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-method) gets a [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Method.html) object from the given symbol. `method(:puts)` gets the `Method` object corresponding to [`Kernel#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

The unary `&` operator calls the [`to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) under the hood:

```
method(:puts).respond_to?(:to_proc) # => true
```

`to_proc` in `Method` returns a `Proc` equivalent to `{ |x| method_name(x) }`:

```
[1, 2, 3].map &method(:String)  # => ["1", "2", "3"]
[1, 2, 3].map { |x| String(x) } # => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i do that        ---->                           words = ["hello", "world", "test"] 
words.map(&:upcase)                                                       the proc is not { |x| method_name(x) } but { |x| x.method_name() } no ? it's change automatically ?

Comment: @unoomad Yep, you're right. But it's not exactly "automatic", it's actually calling [`to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) on `Symbol`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-method) to pull the method off Kernel and store it in a variable "m".

The & operator calls [Method#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Method.html#method-i-to_proc). Stating all this explicitly:

```
irb(main):009:0> m = Kernel.method(:puts); ["hello", "world", "test"].map{|word| m.to_proc.call(word)}
hello
world
test
=> [nil, nil, nil]
```